# jsPlumb How to set dashed line?

Tags: jsplumb

Using jsPlumb needs to implement a function similar to a flow chart. It can save and restore the flow chart. Dragging a node can connect two points. However, after the connection is successful, you need to set the connection type, solid line or dotted line.

[JS codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/tuo-dong-lian-xian-xu-xian-rmymyj?file=%2Findex.html)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41415798/jsplumb-how-to-change-connection-style-from-default-to-dashed

Comment: Thank you very much. I saw this article, but I don’t know if I put the code in the wrong place and it didn’t work.

Comment: I found a way, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, first register the "dashed line type", and then set it through the link object.

1 step：

```js
instance.registerConnectionType("dashConnection", {
  paintStyle: {
    strokeWidth: 1,
    stroke: "green",
    joinstyle: "round",
    // outlineStroke: "white",
    // outlineWidth: 2,
    dashstyle: "2 4",
  },
  hoverPaintStyle: {
    stroke: "green",
    lineWidth: 1,
  },
});
```

2 step：

```js
let connection = instance.connect();
connection.setType('dashConnection')
```